# Problems displaying an existing image in php appengine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

The following code snipet is verbatum from the appengine docs, the url doesn't look right to me but they are doing a lot of stuff differently and this is exactly verbatum what the tutorial said.
A file resides by that name in that bucket.
Tried it with and without the use statement

```
<?php
require_once("includes/c_initialize.php");
require_once 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php';
//use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
$object_image_file = "gs://solomonprofile/profile0.jpg";
$object_image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_image_file, ['size' => 400, 'crop' => true]);
?>
<p>
    <img alt="" src="<?php echo $object_image_url;?>">
</p>
```

Comment: What is value of `$object_image_url`?

Comment: I assume the url string returned by ClousStorageTools static method "getimageservingurl? it returns a string no?

Comment: My concern was the 'google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php'; url, I mean where is the http, or am I just so inside the google world its irrelevant?

Comment: and is the use statement required?

Comment: such an exciting technology, can't wait to really get the car started :)

Comment: I am assuming the class is not getting picked up and the file is not loaded, but again, this is verbatim, can't quite figure out the namespace all either and I never saw a gs til I got here :)

Comment: You should read about namespaces in PHP first: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Automatic_class_loading